# Can I concatenate strings within the prepare() function to insert into specified tables

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation, sql-injection, prepare

I created a database with two tables, each for the type of user (mentor or mentee). The user is asked whether (s)he wants to be a mentor or mentee and then a bunch of other survey questions. Is this possible?

```
        $user_type = $_POST["user_type"];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ' + $user_type + '(value_stream) VALUES (:vs)");            
        $stmt->bindParam(':vs', $value_stream);
```

Comment: How the string *value* supplied to `prepare` is generated is irrelevant to how `prepare` works. However, the string supplied must be valid SQL .. that is not. Try examining the generated string (and reading the SQL error message).

Comment: PHP's concatenation operator is `.` not `+`.

Comment: Make sure to execute it.

Comment: Sure you can do that if you correct the concat. Typically what is asked is can you bind on a tablename or column name or within an `IN` clause, all of which you cant

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_type = $_POST["user_type"];    
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ". $user_type ." '(value_stream) VALUES (:vs)");     
$stmt->bindParam(':vs', $value_stream);
```